# email attachment in php

Tags: php, email

```
 $pieces = explode(",", $sentto);
 for($i=0;$i<count($pieces)-1;$i++)
  {
   $fileatt      = $_FILES['attachcopy']['tmp_name'];
   $fileatt_type = $_FILES['attachcopy']['type'];
   $fileatt_name = $_FILES['attachcopy']['name'];

    $pieces[$i]=$pieces[$i].",";
    $sel="insert into newmessage set sendto='".$pieces[$i]."', 
                                   sendfrom='".$almemailid."',
                                   subject='".$subject."',
                                   message='".$color."',
                           attachment='".$fileatt_name."', 
                       updateddate = now()";


     $selqur=mysql_query($sel) or die("Error (" . mysql_errno() .")" . mysql_error());

     $lastid_id = mysql_insert_id();
     $folderpath = "Attachment/".$lastid_id."".$fileatt_name;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachcopy"]["tmp_name"],$folderpath);
 }
```

Above program runs well in single emailid and send to attachment,
i have send more emailid with attachment there only send emil to all person and attachmnet 
send only first emailid not for other.
i have store all attachment in foldr and attachment files are concodinate with auto increment id.
in the above for loop first time only stored attachment in folder next iteration not
stored in folder

Comment: Please write the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You move the uploaded file from its temporary location (usually in /tmp) to $folderpath. The second time you try to do this, it's no longer going to be in its temporary location, because you already moved it. You need to do that outside of the loop or check if it's already in its new location.